# $addToSet array of object if object doesn't exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have those kind of documents:

```
{
  "_id": "accountId 1",
  "codes": [
    {
      "key": "advantageCode 1",
      "dateBegin": "01/02/2012",
      "dateEnd": "01/02/2013"
    },
    {
      "key": "advantageCode 2",
      "dateBegin": "01/02/2012",
      "dateEnd": "01/02/2013"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to add a code in codes if it doesn't exist. I have tried this:

```
bulkWrite([{updateOne: {
            filter: { _id: commands[0].accountId },
            update: {$addToSet: {codes: {key: commands[0].advantageCode, dateBegin: commands[0].dateBegin, dateEnd: commands[0].dateEnd}}},
            upsert: true
}}])
```

My problem is that the object is always added into the set, even if the key property already exists. It is normal (because it is another reference), but I would like to know how to rebase the $addToSet to the key of the objects.

I need the request to be a bulkwrite, because i gather many different requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using update/aggregation ( since 4.2+) you can do something even better:

```
 db.collection.update({
  "_id": "accountId 1"
 },
 [
 {
  $set: {
  codes: {
    $cond: [
      {
        $in: [
          "advantageCode 2",
          "$codes.key"
        ]
      },
      {
        $map: {
          input: "$codes",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.key",
                      "advantageCode 2"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "dateBegin": "01/02/2020",
                    "dateEnd": "01/02/2021"
                  },
                  {}
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$codes",
          [
            {
              "key": "advantageCode 2",
              "dateBegin": "01/02/2022",
              "dateEnd": "01/02/2023"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
 }
 }
])
```

Explained:

Update dateBegin and dateEnd for codes.key that matches , or if there is no match add the new codes object to the set.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2QHJOFdt2US)

Afcourse , if you only want to $addToSet if key is missing then you can do:

[Playground2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9cT3EZWRzAW)

The bulkWrite operation will look something like this:

```
bulkWrite([{updateOne: {
 filter: { _id: commands[0].accountId },
 update: [{ $set: { codes: { $cond: [ { $in: [commands[0].advantageCode,"$codes.key"]},{ $map: { input: "$codes",in: { $mergeObjects: [ "$$this", {}]}}},{$concatArrays: ["$codes",[{
        "key": commands[0].advantageCode , 
        "dateBegin": commands[0].dateBegin,
        "dateEnd": commands[0].dateEnd
          }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
   }
  }
 }
 ]
 }}])
```

---

If you need to upsert document in case accountId is not found here is the option:

```
 db.collection.update({
 "_id": "accountId 2"
 },
 [
 {
  $set: {
  codes: {
    "$cond": [
      {
        $ne: [
          {
            $type: "$codes"
          },
          "missing"
        ]
      },
      {
        $cond: [
          {
            $in: [
              "advantageCode 3",
              "$codes.key"
            ]
          },
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$codes",
              in: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  "$$this",
                  {}
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$codes",
              [
                {
                  "key": "advantageCode 3",
                  "dateBegin": "01/02/2022",
                  "dateEnd": "01/02/2023"
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "advantageCode 3",
        "dateBegin": "01/02/2022",
        "dateEnd": "01/02/2023"
      }
    ]
    }
   }
  }
  ],
  {
   upsert: true
 })
```

Explained:

1. In case accountId is not found insert new document.
2. In case codes.key is not found insert new object with the new key to the codes array.

[Playground3](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j-a2SOsfjs3)

Comment: in my case, I have to bulkwrite because I regroup many request. How can I adapt this code into thi one:


bulkWrite([{updateOne: {
            filter: { accountId: "accountId 1"},
            update: {$addToSet: {codes: {code: commands[0].advantageCode, dateBegin: commands[0].dateBegin, dateEnd: commands[0].dateEnd}}},
            upsert: true
        }}])

Comment: @Janus updated my answer with bulkWrite example as well

Comment: thanks a lot :)
When I try to add the property "upsert: true" to the request, I have this error:

"MongoBulkWriteError: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing"

Do I miss something ?

Comment: You dont need upsert:true in the agg request ... , do you?

Comment: Yes, because the document needs to be inserted if doesn't exists. If I update without upsert option, it doesn't create the document of it doesn't exists :/

Comment: for upsert:true to work one more condition is needed to check if accountId exists as follow: https://mongoplayground.net/p/j-a2SOsfjs3

Comment: In the end, I can handle this with $addToSet and $pull, as mongo will check the equality of the values of the properties of each objects.

But thanks a lot for your help :)